# Tab Indexing not working in Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

![enter image description here][1]In my application, I have used the MVC telerik grid, bounded with input textboxes. While I run the application in Internet Explorer and the Chrome browser, the tab indexing in working fine and control is moving from one textbox to the other. But when using the Firefox browser, the tab indexing is moving from table row to table row and highlighting the complete cell.

Please help me to fix this.

```
 <div class="appln-cnt-c2">
                <div class="frm-fldrow">
                    <div class="appln-txtrow" style="width: 800px; position: relative; left: 45px;">
                        @{
                            Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.FacultyCompositions)
                               .Name("FacultyComositionGrid")
                               .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(m => m.FacultyCompositionPK))
                               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnComplete("FacultyComositionGrid_onComplete").OnError("FacultyComositionGrid_onError").OnDelete("OnDelete").OnEdit("OnEdit"))
                               .Columns(columns =>
                               {
                                   columns.Bound(m => m.EthnicityDescription)
                                       .Title("<strong>Ethnicity</strong>").Width(180).Filterable(false).Sortable(false).ReadOnly(true);

                                   columns.Template(@<text>

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr id="data">
                                    <td>

                                        <input type="text" class="FacultyCompositionTextbox"   value="@item.FCYear1Male"   @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[0])@(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4"  onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />

                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="text"   value="@item.FCYear1Female" @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[0]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="hidden" value="@item.EthnicityPK"  />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            </text>)
                                                .HeaderTemplate(
                            @<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                @if (Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[0] != "")
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong>@Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[0]</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span>M</span></td>
                                        <td><span>F</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                            </text>).Width(20);
                                   columns.Template(@<text>

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr id="data">
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" value="@item.FCYear2Male"   @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[1]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="position: relative;">
                                            <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="text" value="@item.FCYear2Female" @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[1])  @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
                                            <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="hidden" value="@item.EthnicityPK"  />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            </text>)

                                                .HeaderTemplate(
                            @<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                @if (Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[1] != "")
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong>@Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[1]</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span>M</span></td>
                                        <td><span>F</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                            </text>).Width(20);
                                   columns.Template(@<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr id="data">
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" value="@item.FCYear3Male"   @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[2]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="text" value="@item.FCYear3Female" @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[2]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="hidden" value="@item.EthnicityPK" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </text>)
                                                .HeaderTemplate(
                            @<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                @if (Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[2] != "")
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong>@Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[2]</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span>M</span></td>
                                        <td><span>F</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                            </text>).Width(20);
                                   columns.Template(@<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr id="data">
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" value="@item.FCYear4Male"  @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[3]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"  /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="text" value="@item.FCYear4Female"  @(Model.ReadOnlyFacultyCompositionNew[3]) @(item.DisableCalculatedRow) maxlength="4" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
                                        <input class="FacultyCompositionTextbox" type="hidden" value="@item.EthnicityPK" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </text>)
                                                .HeaderTemplate(
                            @<text>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                @if (Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[3] != "")
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong>@Model.FacultyCompositionColumnHeader[3]</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span>M</span></td>
                                        <td><span>F</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2"><strong></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                        <td><span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                            </text>).Width(60);
                               })
                                            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax())
                                            .ABAGridConfiguration(true)
                                            .KeyboardNavigation(kbd => kbd.EditOnTab(false))
                                            .Render();
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code or it won't be possible to help you accurately.

Comment: Hi Nahuel, I have posted the code could you please check it. I wanted to post a image as well but unfortunately I am not authorized to do so , as I have very less points.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution :)

Steps Invloved : 
1. To find the associated key value with TAB key
2. Once Keydown event fires focus moves to next control

```
$('input.FacultyCompositionTextbox').keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 9) {
            //alert('a');
            $(this).next('input.FacultyCompositionTextbox').focus();
        }
    });
```

Regards,
Praveen Nelge